# MySQLdb Python Trouble creating and using a Table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, twitter

I'm trying to make a mysql table with python 2.7 using MySQLdb.

I've written a program to retrieve tweets based off of a search or "query" from twitter.
I want the tweets to be stored in a MySQL database for later retrieval by their query.

Things to know beforehand: the variable "tweets" is a list of strings.  I want the table to have two parts, the query (what the person searched) and the tweets.

What is supposed to happen, is it should cycle through the list of tweets and insert them into the table.  I keep getting Syntax errors and I'm not sure why.

Maybe there is a better way to do this than how I am currently trying to?  Or maybe I'm just doing it wrong?  All suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

```
#Does the MySQL stuff
db=MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost',user='root',passwd="swag",db="tweets")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TWEETS")

sql = """CREATE TABLE TWEETS (
         QUERY  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
         TWEET  BLOB,
         )"""

cursor.execute(sql)

#Inserts tweets into MySQLdb
for i in range(0,len(tweets)):
    sql = "INSERT INTO TWEETS(QUERY, \
           TWEET) \
           VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % \
           (query, tweets[i])

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()
```

Comment: how do you sanitize your tweets?  What if someone puts sql in their tweets?

Comment: I cannot seem to post the tweet i want.  [SO stops me lol](http://xkcd.com/327/).  But it would effectively drop your table if you inserted it.

Comment: I currently don't have any sanitization yet, but this is just the back end for now, I'll do that all later.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean paqogomez.. sorry :) I do like the comic though.... I'm kind of a mySQL noob

Comment: imagine if someone tweeted little bobby table's name, but instead of students, they put tweets.  When you inserted that into your database, it would execute the drop.

Comment: Ahh I get it. Thanks.  Anywayss... any idea on why im getting an error?

Comment: I think your problem is exactly that.  You are bringing in random text and expecting the interpolated sql to be syntactically valid.  What if there is a single quote in your text, what if there is a SQL keyword in your text?  You need to [parameterize your sql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html).

Comment: I think my error is from syntax:Warning (from warnings module):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Projects\Python\SearchTwitter.py", line 50, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;)

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. Print out the SQL from your app and run it against your database.  It should become clear.